# Designing a Bayesian A/B experiment

Tags: bayesian, experiment-design, ab-test

Problem: We wanted to design a Bayesian A/B experiment to explore monetization strategies that can help publishers improve fill rates, eCPM and ARPDAU.

'Control' and 'Treatment' are two mutually exclusive cohorts of users, and we are using Facebook PlanOut for random assignment of users into these variants with different weights.

1. How do I set an informed prior? How many data points do I need to have an informed prior?
2. Can the prior data be collected from a random sample of users? How do we best represent historical seasonality?
3. For the posterior I have the following data; user_id, timestamp, variant(control/treatment),  fill (binary), revenue. Is this data sufficient? How do I use this data to evaluate which variant has a higher chance to beat all when it comes to eCPM (Revenue / Impressions), where impressions = COUNT(fill == TRUE)?